# Turn Off Row Names when Printing a Table

Tags: r, gridextra, r-grid

This is a nifty way to print a table.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
d <- head(iris[,1:3])
grid.table(d)
```

I think the row names uglify the table though. So let's turn them off.

```
grid.table(d, row.names = FALSE)
```

Woops, that doesn't work and gives me this error.

> Error in gtable_table(d, name = "core", fg_fun = theme$core$fg_fun,
>   bg_fun = theme$core$bg_fun,  :    unused argument (row.names = FALSE)

What does work to turn off the row names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
grid.table(d, rows = NULL)
```